# IDEA reports Error with Android Gradle Build Target

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I cannot build the project using Idea, I get following message right after launch:-

```
Error:Android Gradle Build Target: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation 'C:\Users\username\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.11-bin\4h5v8877arc3jhuqbm3osbr7o7\gradle-1.11'.

content of following directory:
c:\Users\malousek\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.11-bin\4h5v8877arc3jhuqbm3osbr7o7\gradle-1.11\ 
is following:
bin
init.d
lib
media
changelog, license, notice,



IDEA Settings for Gradle:
Use Default Gradle Wrapper (recommended)
```

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried Intellij 13 It had many problems with Gradle (1.11+), use Intellij EAP 14 or switch to Android Studio.

You can try removing "C:\Users\username.gradle\wrapper\dists\" directory and resync your gradle project.